# A recommendation how to create an info monitor server

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, streaming

I want to create a data streaming server, and I need a solution, cuz I can't understand what I should to use.

Okay, I have a central home server, which contains infos about temperature, light, motion sensors, music on my central home sound bus and more. And I want to create solution like:

1. Server continuously sends the data to the local network via port.
2. And at any time I have an opportunities to connect. For e.g. I connect to 192.168.1.2:1234 and immediately start to listening all information. I can do it from any clients and at the same time. **And the server may not even know about connections. It only sends the data to the local network via port, and nothing more.**

**UPD:**
I used TCP protocol to exchange the data between server and clients, but it wasn't a good solution, cuz it's not suit to my described idea.

Comment: So, you're looking for us to recommend something or write something?  Sorry, that's off topic.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I have refined the topic. Yes, I'm looking for a recommendation